# Trouble converting UTC time received from database to local time

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, utc

I have recently been attempting to convert a string representing a time in UTC to a local non-UTC format.

For example, this is one of the strings I am attempting to convert:

```
2017-04-07T16:00:00.000Z
```

And I am trying to get it into the US datetime (M/d/yyyy, etc.) format of:

```
4/7/2017 4:00 PM
```

But for some reason the output I am receiving is in the European datetime (d/M/yyyy, etc.) format of:

```
7/4/2017 4:00 PM
```

My code for attempting to convert the string is as follows:

```
DateTimeOffset start_time = DateTimeOffset.Parse(event_time);

// In Unity, debugging time without offset

Debug.Log(start_time.LocalDateTime);
```

I have attempted to use ParseExact and other methods to get the output in my desired format, but I haven't been having any luck so far. What am I doing 
wrong?

Comment: If you are sure that you will always receive such output format "7/4/2017 4:00 PM" you could use the `String.Split` function and and store the values of the date. You can then rearrange it however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the format in `ToString` method to get the `M/d/yyyy`, see more about [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Debug.Log(start_time.LocalDateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm tt"));
```